# Given the HttpContext.Handler how can i register Script on startup in MVC3

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a page which open a new window with External Url (Twitter Authentication Url) now that window will authenticate the user and call back to an action method , in that action method i have to close the current window (popUp) and inform the opener that authentication succeeded,

in web forms i used to do something like this on a (postback):

```
            (HttpContext.Current.Handler as System.Web.UI.Page).ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(
            this.GetType(),
            "winPop",
            "window.opener.doSomething(true);window.close()",
            true);
```

in MVC i tried this but didnt work since there is no Current but there is :

```
HttpContext.CurrentHandler
```

which can be casted to `Mvc.MvcHandler` now the question arise i know MVC is totally Different but is there is any way to register script which would run at the response startup ?

I know i can make an extra view and open it in the new window and then redirect to Twitter Url and then on the call back to the same Window i would call the script simply window.opener......etc but that would mean i have to make an extra view that only have nothing but a line of javascript at the startup, so i was wondering if i can do one of the following :

Option 1: Register Start up Script like i explained above.
Option 2: Return javascript code that runs at the client (no actual view).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply forget what you were doing classic WebForms as it won't be of much of a help in ASP.NET MVC.

In ASP.NET MVC you have Models, Controllers and Views (as its name suggests). So if you wanted to call a javascript function in your view and pass it some value from your model you could do the following:

```
@model MyViewModel
<script type="text/javascript">
    alert(@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.SomeValue)));
</script>
```

where obviously your controller action will populate this model and pass it to the view:

```
public ActionResult Foo()
{
    var model = new MyViewModel
    {
        SomeValue = "Hello world"
    };
    return View(model);
}
```

and of course a corresponding model:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public string SomeValue { get; set; }
}
```

See? Model, View, Controller.

---

UPDATE:

> in that action method i have to close the current window (popUp) and
>   inform the opener that authentication succeeded,

You don't need a model in this simple case:

```
public ActionResult CallbackAction()
{
    return View();
}
```

and inside `CallbackAction.cshtml`:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.opener.doSomething(true);
    window.close();
</script>
```

Comment: thanks for your response Darin, i know the concept of MVC, the situation is more complicated than just simple model view controller that is why im trying to accomplish it this way but i guess now i have to explain the whole situation i will edit my question with more details

Comment: @Stacker, no the situation in ASP.NET MVC shouldn't be more complicated than a model, view and controller. Or if it is, you are probably doing something wrong. Well, yes, you guessed it right, you will have to explain your situation.

Comment: @Stacker what about my answer ?

Comment: i upvoted your answer dknaack but there is no view in the opened-window so it doesn't have a layout so the script wont run...

Comment: i tried your code @DarinDimitrov but i donno why it didnt execute the script but instead it wrote it to the page !

Comment: @Stacker, does your `CallbackAction.cshtml` view looks exactly as what I have shown? Also is the `CallbackAction` action being executed? Is there a redirect happening from Twitter to this action?

Comment: @Stacker the `ViewBag` is available in every view. So you if you have no `_Layout.cshtml` put this in the file there your `<head>` section is.

Comment: @darinDimitrov there is no callbackAction.cshtml and this is what rise the problem, im asking if its technically possible to return just action script without a view that runs on the client to close the window and inform the opener without (Making extra view).

Comment: @Stacker, what prevents you from adding this view? I mean you could always have your controller action `return Content("<html><head><script type=\"text/javascript\">window.opener.doSomething(true); window.close();</script></head><body></body></html>", "text/html");` but that would be freakishly insane. Please promise me to never do anything like that in any ASP.NET MVC application that you care about.

Comment: nothing!, i was just asking if its technically possible to do it without a view as i dont want to make a view which does nothing but having a line of script to execute i think it would make sense to just return the script.

Comment: @Stacker, it's all about separation of concerns in ASP.NET MVC. So, yeah, go ahead and add that view.

Comment: this works ! no extra view and i can always return scripts that runs , actually im thinking of making an extension now that just do that!

Answer (score 2):

#### Description

This does not exist in MVC but you can use a `ViewModel` or the `ViewBag` for this.

#### Sample

**_Layout.cshtml**

```
....
<head>
<title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
@if (ViewBag.StartScript != null)
{
    <script>
        @Html.Raw(ViewBag.StartScript);
    </script>
}
....
```

**Your ActionMethod**

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    ViewBag.StartScript = "alert('Hello World')";
    return View();

}
```